# Python: count number of empty cells in excel sheet of data

Tags: python, excel

I'm relatively new to Python, and I'm attempting to count the number of empty cells in an excel sheet filled with data. To test the program, I've been deleting some values so that the cells are empty: my code is below

```
import xlrd   
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl 
df = pd.read_excel('5train.xls')

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('5train.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('5train')

#Task starts here
empty = 0
row_data = worksheet.nrows - 1
row = 0
cell = 0
while row < row_data:
    if worksheet.cell(0, 0).value == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
        empty += 1
        cell += 1
    else:
        pass
    row += 1
print("Number of empty cells in data sheet:", empty)
```

However, the code will consistently print "Number of empty cells in data sheet: 0" no matter how many cells I empty. Any pointers? Thank you!

Comment: An excel sheet contains 1.04 million rows and hundreds of columns.  You want to count every blank cell?  Or you have your data in some table format, and want to count blanks within that table range?

Answer (score 1):

You always check the same cell in your loop:

```
if worksheet.cell(0, 0).value == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
```

Only the cell in row 0 and columns 0 is checked if it is empty.

Comment: How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each row through the last row that contains data using `.get_rows()`, then count the empty cells by checking the value of each cell in each row.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('5train.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('5train')

empty_cells = 0
for row in worksheet.get_rows():
    empty_cells += sum(0 if c.value else 1 for c in row)
```

If you want to make it a one-liner, you can use:

```
empty_cells = sum(0 if c.value else 1 for row in worksheet.get_rows() for c in row)
```